# I am trying to build my website on CloudFlare using React.JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, cloudflare

I am trying to build on my website using the Git repo on Cloudflare, but everytime I build it I run into this error.

I have tried deleting the yarn.lock, then yarn cache clean -all, then yarn install. But it always gives me this error. I am kinda new to web development.

This is my git repo: https://github.com/BuraiStar/BrianWongPortfolio

```
> 01:47:43.715  ➤ YN0000: ┌ Post-resolution validation
> 01:47:43.716  ➤ YN0028: │ The lockfile would have been modified by this install, which is explicitly forbidden.
> 01:47:43.716  ➤ YN0000: └ Completed
> 01:47:43.716  ➤ YN0000: Failed with errors in 17s 450ms
> 01:47:43.849  Error: Exit with error code: 1
> 01:47:43.849      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/snapshot/dist/run-build.js)
> 01:47:43.850      at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:652:26)
> 01:47:43.850      at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:537:28)
> 01:47:43.850      at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
> 01:47:43.859  Failed: build command exited with code: 1
> 01:47:44.930  Failed: error occurred while running build command
```

I am hoping to be able to publish my website for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the environmental variable, `YARN_VERSION` = 1?

> - [React app cant build in pages - Developers / Cloudflare Pages - Cloudflare Community](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/react-app-cant-build-in-pages/565639)